# How to send form data to the server api with angular 2?

Tags: angular, http, typescript, post

I'm trying to post data from a small registration form to the server

I've been stuck in this since three days now i don't know how to do it, i'm still beginner in Angular 2, I need some guidance in how to post this data:
my html:

```
<form>
  <div class="row col-md-12">
<input (keyup.enter) = "userName(name)" #name type="text" 
class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-3 first-name-input add-account-inputs" 
placeholder="First name" >
<input type="text" class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-3 last-name-input 
add-account-inputs" placeholder="Last name" >
  </div>
<input type="email" class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-6 add-account-
inputs" placeholder="Email" >
<input type="password" class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-6 add-account-
inputs" id="password" placeholder="Password" >
<input type="password" class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-6 add-account-
inputs" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm password" >
  </form>
```

My component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
declare const $;

@Component({
selector: 'app-add-account',
templateUrl: './add-account.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-account.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AddAccountComponent implements OnInit {
name: any[];
password: any[];
email: any[];
userNames: any[];
private url = 'i deleted it because it belongs to the company api';

constructor(private http: Http) {
}

userName(input: HTMLInputElement) {
let user = {name: input.value};
input.value = '';
this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(user))
  .subscribe(response => {
    user['id'] = response.json().id;
    this.user.push(name);
    console.log(response.json());
  });
} }
```

As you can see, I tried to post username only just to test but it didn't work and I know something is wrong or missing but I don't know what it is.
Also I want to know what if I'm trying to post more than one data, like username and email, how to write it.

If you have any demos or live examples send it, if you need any more data or anything that I didn't write just ask.

Comment: can u send the API's expected type.?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? What is the error that is displayed? Did you provide `Http` in your `module.ts`?

Comment: It's a post type api, is this is what you meant?

Comment: i mean you data json schema. Thanks btw, try importing
 import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http'; and use that in the constructor as private property http. Import HttpClientModule in App.module.ts

Comment: @YounesM       I'm using angular 4, yes i provided http you can see it in the first lines of my ts, this is the error on the console appears when i press enter:

Comment: core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (add-account.component.ts:50)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:239)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:127)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1556)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)

Comment: im very thankful for your help but how to use it in the constructor? im a beginner @JinsPeter

Comment: this is my json response:
{
    "scode": 405,
    "message": "some Error happened",
    "data": [],
    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "The name field is required."
        ],
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ],
        "password": [
            "The password field is required."
        ],
        "type_id": [
            "The type id field is required."
        ],
        "school_id": [
            "The school id field is required."
        ]
    }
}
i hope that this is what you meant @JinsPeter

Comment: There is a difference between importing a module and providing it. If you  need to use Http (Or HttpClient since you're on angular 4) you should import HttpClientModule in your app.module.ts : https://angular.io/guide/http#setup-installing-the-module

Comment: @YounesM       ok i imported the httpclientmodule in my ts file and provided it in y constructor, now there is a different error in the console
ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 20, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}

Comment: @MohamedWahshey it is better if we create a plunker.

Comment: Ok i created an empty plunkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/VbXXr1tXwJ5nAtnMUmIb?p=catalogue   @JinsPeter

Comment: Ok i created an empty stack blitz :D :D @YounesM
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxrhfz

Comment: @YounesM nice... now that i tried it.

Comment: @MohamedWahshey can u create ur component there and share??

Comment: ok i will try but that means i have to put the company api, i can give you teamviewer access to my laptop, would it be okay? @JinsPeter

Comment: @MohamedWahshey I will share a stackblitz

Comment: this is a public api link btw
http://easyschools.org/crm/crm/public/api/en/schools/create/step5

you can test with this @JinsPeter

Comment: try this with the stack blits i shared man https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vymqyi

Comment: @MohamedWahshey did u get an idea.?? or do i need to strip OFF ur css classes from the html. Plz respond and vote the answer, if it worked plz accept answer

Comment: what do you mean by stripping off my classes???
i wrote a reply on the answer you provided @JinsPeter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vymqyi)

**The component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
declare const $;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-account',
  templateUrl: './add-account.component.html',
  //styleUrls: ['./add-account.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AddAccountComponent implements OnInit {
  name: any[];
  password: any[];
  email: any[];
  userNames: any[];
  private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){


    }
    // userName(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    //   let user = {name: input.value};
    //   debugger;
    //   //input.value = '';
    //   this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(user))
    //     .subscribe(response => {
    //       alert(response);
    //     },(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    //       alert(err);
    //   });
    // }

    onSubmit(form: NgForm){
      var data = form.value;
      debugger;
      var myPostObject = {
        firstName:data.firstname,
        lastName:data.lastname,
        email:data.email,
        passWord:data.password,
      }
      this.http.post(this.url, myPostObject)
        .subscribe(response => {
          debugger;
          console.log(response);
        },(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err);
      });
    }
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<form #registerForm="ngForm" >
  <div class="row col-md-12">
<input  name="firstname" ngModel #firstname="ngModel" type="text" 
class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-3 first-name-input add-account-inputs" 
placeholder="First name" >
<input type="text" name="lastname" ngModel #lastname="ngModel" class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-3 last-name-input 
add-account-inputs" placeholder="Last name" >
  </div>
<input type="email" name="email" ngModel #email="ngModel" class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-6 add-account-
inputs" placeholder="Email" >
<input type="password" name="password" ngModel #password="ngModel" class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-6 add-account-
inputs" id="password" placeholder="Password" >
<input type="password" (keyup.enter)="onSubmit(registerForm)"  class="rounded-inputs25 col-md-6 add-account-
inputs" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm password" >
  </form>
```

Comment: It's working on stack blitz but when i run it on my project it directs me to the debugger when i press enter to submit, im very thankful for you because you're wasting time to help me but can you please guide me through the final step, how can i make it work with my api key on my project? what could be missing?

Comment: do u have an key for that api that u need to pass?

Comment: this is the public api key
easyschools.org/crm/crm/public/api/en/schools/create/step5

Comment: did u try calling that with required posyObject without json stringify?

Comment: i just put the link instead of the link you used

Comment: do u have any experience in web application development

Comment: team viewer now?

Comment: yes i have but ui only not angular, r u mocking me?

Comment: tell me where to send you my team viewer id and password

Comment: ok with Team viewer now.? This angular post is just another way to do jQuery ajax...Your api at the url sends a response even if there is a validation error which is to be solved by your server side team. now the current code at stackblitz will work for u i belive

Comment: here. once i say. u can delete. r u in india btw?

Comment: yes im ok with team viewer now, aha ths issue is i dont know how to push data to the json array inside the api, where would you like me to send you my team viewer details?

Comment: i'm not Indian, did u born with your experience? you didn't need any help at the beginning?

Comment: do you have fb or whatsapp to send you my team viewer details on?

Comment: No man, I did not mean any offence.. I wanted to know if u are familiar with post.

Comment: and sorry about your question that i dont have any exp. at web app dev. i thought you were trying to mock me

Comment: no, im not familiar, this is the very first time with me to deal with back-end data, im a front end developer but now we're developing an Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using reactive forms from Angular? What you are doing seems a lot complicated for no reason.

Please read: [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). That should give you enough information on how to work with forms.

Once you define form controls you can subscribe to valueChanges and react accordingly, while still having access to form (and control) values.

Comment: will i be able to post it to the server?

Comment: i saw the topic and the live example but i dont know  if this will make me able to post it to the server

Comment: Http service is the one making you able to post to server. And yes, it does help you post to server.

Comment: Also, please use Angular 4/5 and HttpClient, unless you need XSRF over cross domain. HttpClient is easier and cleaner than the old (and deprecated) Http.