# Send JSON data from angular 7 UI to Spring Controller

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

I want to send JSON data from Angular 7 UI to Spring MVC Controller, and save the data into mysql db.

I can send the data from Spring Controller to Angular, but i can't seem to find a way to do the opposite.
can anyone help me with some references or the code for it.

**in .ts file**

```
this.http.post("someurl/addData",event.newData).subscribe(response => { console.log(response);})
```

**and in Spring controller :-**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addData",method=RequestMethod.GET) public void addDataintoDb(PojoClass pojo){ System.out.println(pojo.start); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the below method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addData",method=RequestMethod.GET) public void 
addDataintoDb(PojoClass pojo){ System.out.println(pojo.start); }
```

Instead of GET change it to POST.

and add **@RequestBody** => addDataintoDb(@RequestBody PojoClass pojo)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addData",method=RequestMethod.POST) public void 
addDataintoDb(@RequestBody PojoClass pojo){ System.out.println(pojo.start); }
It will work.
```

By default angular post body as json, Use below if you have any mismatch in request body type:-

```
 let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
 this.http.post("someurl/addData",event.newData,{ headers: headers 
 }).subscribe(response => { console.log(response);})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to send data to the spring MVC controller

https://www.programmergate.com/pass-data-from-jsp-to-spring-controller/

This is to send data using angular

[How to send form data to the server api with angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399224/how-to-send-form-data-to-the-server-api-with-angular-2)

https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me, can you help me with this.

Comment: Post your code in the question and update it don't put it in comments

Answer (score 0):

**Assume that your Controller (api ):**

// http get call with Long id

```
@GetMapping("/find-by-id")                            
public Response getEmployeeById(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
    return employeeServiced.getEmployeeById(id);
}
```

// http post call with Object,

**Java Object property and JSON Object property must be the same for automatic binding.**

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public Response saveEmployee(@RequestBody(required = false) EmployeeEntity reqObj) {
    return employeeServiced.saveEmployee(reqObj);
}
```

**java Orm Entity:**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class EmployeeEntity  {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long id;

   private String empName;

   private String gender; 

}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EmployeeService {


  @Autowired
  UserDao userDao;


  public void saveEmployee(EmployeeEntity user){
    userDao.add(user);
 }


 public User findByIdPost(long id){
    return userDao.getById(id);
 }

 public User getEmployeeById(long id){
    return userDao.getEmployeeById(id);
 }

}
```

**In Angular Call api (Send Json data to Server side ):**

In Angular Component **(For get Request premitive data sending )**:

```
      getEmployeeById(id: number):void{
       this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(id).subscribe(
        res => {
        if(res.success){
          console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log(" error: ", err);
        })
      }
```

In Angular Service:

```
      getEmployeeById(id: any) {
        return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8090/employee/find-by-id'`, {
          params: new HttpParams().set('id', id)
        })
      }
```

**In Angular, Call api (Send Json Object data to Server side ):**

In Angular Component **(For get Request Object data sending )**:

```
      OnSaveEmployee(): void {
        let empObj = {          // For Object binding Json Object property and java Entity property must be same name.
        "empName":"IMRAN"
        "gender":"Male"
        }

        this.employeeService.saveEmployee(empObj).subscribe(
          res => {
          if(res.success){
            console.log(res)
           }else{
             console.log("getPatientDemographyInfo error:",res);
           }
          },
          err => {
            console.log("Priority list error: ", err);
          }
        )
      }
```

In Angular Service:

```
     saveEmployee(empObj:any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8090/employee/save", 
        empObj).pipe(
          map((data: any) => data
        ));
      }
```

Complete Project [here](https://github.com/imrangthub/angular-multi-modules-project)

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are sending a POST request from the Angular side, but have annotated you Spring controller's method as accepting a GET. So, I'm assuming that you get a 404 / Not Found, because a there is no method in the Spring app to handle a GET.

To fix this, change

`@RequestMapping(value="/addData",method=RequestMethod.GET) public void addDataintoDb(PojoClass pojo){ System.out.println(pojo.start); }`

to

`@RequestMapping(value="/addData",method=RequestMethod.POST) public void addDataintoDb(PojoClass pojo){ System.out.println(pojo.start); }`